# the select menu does not behave as it is expected

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash. I want to have a select menu in bash. It has four options. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
while true; do
    clear
    options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Exit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "Option 1")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Option 2")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Option 3")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                firefox http://localhost:8000/browser/
                break
                ;;
            "Exit")
                break 2
                ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
    done
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
done
```

Here is the output:

```
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Exit
Please enter your choice: 1
#you chose choice 1 which is Option 1
Press [Enter] key to continue...
```

This code works perfectly fine, except when I press 3. In this case after printing the message I want, the browser is opened using this command:

```
firefox http://localhost:8000/browser/
```

after opening the browser, I expect my code to display this message:

```
Press [Enter] key to continue...
```

but it doesn't until I close the browser. What's wrong?

Comment: So you want to run firefox _concurrently_ with your script?

Comment: I want my script open the browser and then display "Press [Enter] key to continue..." as option1 & option2.

Comment: So you want both your browser and the process to run at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong?

Great code!

If you want to run the process `firefox` in the background just add `&` to the end of the command.

```
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            firefox http://localhost:8000/browser/ &
            break
```